# Wrapper Function For Date Truncation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm not a fan of working with dates in SQL Server and can never remember how to do some simple tasks off the top of my head.

One of them is truncating today's date.
`convert(datetime, datediff(day, 0, getdate()))`

I wanted to start creating wrapper functions for these for readability and reference.

```sql
create or alter function
    /* Returns the date as of today at midnight (truncated)
     *
     * i.e.
     *   getdate() -> 2023-12-04 10:26
     *   date_today_midnight() -> 2023-12-04 00:00
     */
    dbo.date_today_midnight()
returns
    datetime
as begin
    return convert(datetime, datediff(day, 0, getdate()));
end
```

Unfortunately there's a big performance hit when I swap my new function into the where clause.

```sql
select * from aTable where aDate >= convert(datetime, datediff(day, 0, getdate()));
-- runtime < 1s
```

```sql
select * from aTable where aDate >= date_today_midnight();
-- runtime > 10s
```

From my understanding, the problem is related to `getdate()` being a runtime constant function. So SQL server knows to swap that out with a constant at the beginning of query execution. Is there a way I can mark my own function as a runtime constant?

I tried using a CTE to get the date first, but that somehow resulted in even worse performance.

```sql
with dates as (select date_today_midnight() as today)
select * from aTable join dates on 1=1 where aDate >= dates.today;
-- runtime > 50s
```

Comment: If you want to truncate to today's date, why not just `CONVERT`/`CAST` the value to a `date`? Are you using SQL Server 2005, and so don't have access to the data type? If so, the real problem is you are using a version that has been end of life for ~8 years.

Comment: I didn't realize `cast(getdate() as date)` would truncate. Beyond that, I would still prefer having a function to do it, since the next time I google how to truncate a date I'll probably find `convert(datetime, datediff(day, 0, getdate()))` again. I'd like to build a suite of common date functions so that I don't have to look them up too, like `date_yesterday_midnight()`, `date_tomorrow_midnight()`, `date_truncate(date)`. But they are less valuable if I have to remember never to use them in a where clause.

Comment: If you are on 2022, then you also have access to `DATETRUNC`. The syntax you have used, in truth, hasn't been needed since 2008.

Comment: `CAST(YourValue AS date)` or the new `DATETRUNC(day, YourValue)` Don't bother with a Scalar User Defined Function, they have serious performance issues. Sounds like you just need a cheatsheet somewhere. If you mark your function `WITH SCHEMABINDING` you may at least improve the performance when used with a constant.

Comment: *Inline* Table Type User Defined Functions are fine, @Charlieface, it's just multi-line functions that aren't (and Scalar User Defined Functions are often multi-line).

Comment: if you use inline table valued functions, these usually won't affect your performance (too much).

Comment: @Charlieface looks like it. I wish there were an option to declare my function as a runtime constant. Maybe someday.

Comment: Scalar User Defined functions are inlinable in newer versions of SQL Server, @Jamie , but we don't know what version you are using and, honestly, I see no need for something as trivial as this. SQL isn't like C#, it does *not* benefit from putting *every* reusable bit of code in a function/view (such designs often a result in (significant) performance issues).

Comment: @ThomA I think there is value in having these functions available. It's possible to have your cheat sheet in the database. As well as make your queries more readable (subjective). It also solves refactoring problems. i.e. if a new way to truncate dates emerges eventually that is better than what I currently have, I can update my function, not every query where I used it. The problem is performance, which is what I was hoping to solve here. I'll add the server version to the question.

Comment: Sure, if performance is something you actively avoid, @Jamie , then having these functions is fine, but you specifically state performance is important and so those functions don't have a place in your design. Personally, I think `CONVERT(date,GETDATE())` and `DATETRUNC(DAY,GETDATE())` is very readable; one clearly *converts* the current date and time to a `date` and other Truncates the current date and time to a `DAY`.

Comment: @ThomA this problem extends beyond just simple date truncation. And you're saying *if performance is something you actively avoid* ignores the fact that that's the exact problem I'm trying to resolve in my approach. If I could make performant inline functions, that wouldn't really be an argument.

Comment: @Jamie there is already a performant inline function, `CAST` is exactly that. This is already available to you, it seems your argument against using it is that you can't remember it - how is it less memorable than a UDF?

Comment: @PatrickHurst I work with several different databases, and they use different methods. If I have these in the database, they are not just on my cheat sheet, but available to everyone. When I googled how to get yesterday's date at midnight, I found what I found. This is something that applies beyond just date truncation, and I'm glad to hear that MS is making strides toward allowing users to create performant inline functions. I must not be the only one who sees value in it.

Comment: As I (now) note in my answer, however, @Jamie, the use of `GETDATE()` in a scalar user defined function will *never* be inlinable.

Comment: `CAST` is ANSI-SQL standard, you should be able to use it in the majority of SQL dialects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the method you have, it hasn't been needed since SQL Server 2005. The `date` data type was added in SQL Server 2008 so there is no reason to use a "quirky" solution like you have here. if you want get the current date, as a date, then just `CONVERT`/`CAST` the value to a `date`:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) AS CurrentDate;
```

As for using a function, again don't. User Defined Scalar functions are known to not be performant, as historically they weren't inlinable. In 2019+ (not what you are using) inlinable scalar functions were added. however, they have had also had performance issues, and the "solution" has often been for Microsoft add more and more [requirements (caveats)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver16#requirements) to causing a function to be (not) inlinable. Using `GETDATE()` in scalar function will cause it to **not** be inlinable:

> A scalar T-SQL UDF can be inlined if all of the following conditions are true:
>
> - ...
> - The UDF doesn't invoke any intrinsic function that is either time-dependent (such as `GETDATE()`) or has side effects <sup>3</sup> (such as `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`).
> - ...
>
> <sup>3</sup> Intrinsic functions whose results depend upon the current system time are time-dependent. An intrinsic function that may update some internal global state is an example of a function with side effects. Such functions return different results each time they're called, based on the internal state.

You could use an inline table value function, however, for something as *trivial* as this, there is entirely no need for such a function. `CONVERT`/`CAST` the value to a `date` is more than simple enough.

If you were in SQL Server 2022+, you would also have access to the `DATETRUNC` function:

```sql
SELECT DATETRUNC(DAY, GETDATE());
```

Unlike `CONVERT`/`CAST`, this would retain the data type of the input expression, so would return `2023-12-04T00:00:00.000` rather than `2023-12-04`.

Comment: This is great info, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just for posterity, here's an inline version if your function:

```sql
create or alter function
    /* Returns the date as of today at midnight (truncated)
     *
     * i.e.
     *   getdate() -> 2023-12-04 10:26
     *   date_today_midnight() -> 2023-12-04 00:00
     */
    dbo.date_today_midnight()
returns table as
    return select convert(datetime, datediff(day, 0, getdate())) as today
```

Usage style #1:

```sql
select *
from sys.objects so
where so.create_date < (select today from dbo.date_today_midnight())
```

Usage style #2:

```sql
select *
from sys.objects so
CROSS APPLY dbo.date_today_midnight() t
where so.create_date < t.today
```

If you see the QP selection, you will notice that function call has been inlined:

```
[master].[sys].[sysschobjs].[created] as [o].[created]<CONVERT(datetime,datediff(day,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000',getdate()),0) AND [master].[sys].[sysschobjs].[nsclass] as [o].[nsclass]=(0)
AND [master].[sys].[sysschobjs].[pclass] as [o].[pclass]=(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an inline TVF. It's not exactly what I wanted but more or less accomplishes what I was going for with no noticeable impact to the query time.

```sql
create or alter function
    tvf_dates(@date datetime)
returns
    table
as return (
    select
        @date as reference_date,
        cast(@date as date) as midnight,
        dateadd(day, -1, @date) as previous,
        cast(dateadd(day, -1, @date) as date) as previous_midnight,
        dateadd(day, 1, @date) as next,
        cast(dateadd(day, 1, @date) as date) as next_midnight,
        getdate() as now,
        cast(getdate() as date) as today,
        dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as yesterday,
        cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date) as yesterday_midnight,
        dateadd(day, 1, getdate()) as tomorrow,
        cast(dateadd(day, 1, getdate()) as date) as tomorrow_midnight
)
```

```sql
select aTable.* from aTable cross join tvf_dates(getdate()) where aDate >= dates.today;
```

Comment: Considering you have passing a parameter, and returning all those columns, this now feels like you should be using a calendar table.